# Is it possible to display a still image in an AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm trying to make a program where I need to show images and videos on an external screen. So I have a Table View where I can enter names and links to video files (mp4 for now) and image files (jpg for now).

I can't find the way to display still images in AVPlayer.

So to visualize the video files or the images, I created an AVPlayer and an UIImageView which have the same sizes. The AVPlayer is placed above the UIImageView.

If I want to display an image, I hide the AVPlayer.

```
if ([self selectedVideoURL]!=nil){
    NSString *myString = [[self selectedVideoURL] absoluteString];
    NSString *extension = [myString substringFromIndex: [myString length] - 3];
    if (![extension isEqual:@"jpg"]){
        self.playerView.hidden = false;
        [self playingVideo:[self selectedVideoURL]];
    }
    else{
        self.playerView.hidden = true;
        [self displayingImage:[self selectedVideoURL]];
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make it simpler?

Thanks...